# Android Studio: Create JUnit test case with template?

Tags: class, android-studio, junit, testcase

It is possible to create a JUnit test class in Android Studio as it is known from Eclipse? That means creating a class with some defined values like @Before, @After, and so on.

What I mean is this...
[image: JUnit]

Comment: I am looking for same! Did you find any solution?

Comment: @AndiGeeky No, I didn't want to waste too much time for this. I already wasted so much time with this Android Studio crap which is full of bugs.